# Retrieving values of an object from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Pardon the example but in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A { 
private:
    string theName;
    int theAge;
public:
    A() : theName(""), theAge(0) { }
    A(string name, int age) : theName(name), theAge(age) { }
};

class B {
private:
    A theArray[1];
public:
    void set(const A value) {theArray[0] = value; }
    A get() const { return theArray[0]; } 
};

int main()
{
    A man("Bob", 25);
    B manPlace;
    manPlace.set(man);
    cout << manPlace.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible for me to retrieve the contents of the "man" object in main when I call manPlace.get()? My intention is to print both the name (Bob) and the age (25) when I call manPlace.get(). I want to store an object within an array within another class and I can retrieve the contents of said array within the main.

Comment: `const A& temp = manPlace.get();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `ostream::operator<<` on your A class to accomplish that - otherwise the format how age and name should be generated as text-output is undefined (and they are private members of your A class).

Take a look at the reference for [ostream::operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/). For your A class, such a operator could be defined like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, A &a) {
  out << "Name: " << a.theName << std::endl;
  out << "Age: " << a.theAge << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

Which would output something like:

```
Name: XX
Age: YY
```

So your complete code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
  string theName;
  int theAge;
public:
  A() : theName(""), theAge(0) { }
  A(string name, int age) : theName(name), theAge(age) { }
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, A &a) {
    out << "Name: " << a.theName << std::endl;
    out << "Age: " << a.theAge << std::endl;
    return out;
  }
};

class B {
private:
  A theArray[1];
public:
  void set(const A value) { theArray[0] = value; }
  A get() const { return theArray[0]; }
};

int main()
{
  A man("Bob", 25);
  B manPlace;
  manPlace.set(man);
  cout << manPlace.get();
  return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
Name: Bob
Age: 25
```